# Location of com.amazonaws.services.simpleemailv2 package in AWS SES Java SDK jars

Tags: amazon-ses, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I want to make use of the AWS-SES sdk's `putAccountSuppressionAttributes` functionality. From AWS' documentation they say that this functionality is available in the AWS Java SDK. I have managed to find the class and method in [their javadoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleemailv2/AmazonSimpleEmailServiceV2.html#putAccountSuppressionAttributes-com.amazonaws.services.simpleemailv2.model.PutAccountSuppressionAttributesRequest-), but cannot seem to find the `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceV2` interface or the entire `com.amazonaws.services.simpleemailv2` package in any of the AWS SDK jars.
I have tried `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:1.11.712` (the latest `1.X` version of the SDK at time of writing) and `software.amazon.awssdk:ses:2.10.53` (looking for the [`software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2` package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleemailv2/package-summary.html) instead) but there the `v2` packages are not present.

Which jars are these `v2` ses packages/apis provided in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Support have clarified that it is available in `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sesv2`